# check status of VPN connection status for openVPN on Android

Tags: android, vpn, openvpn

Is there any way to get the status of VPN connectivity on android 4.using openVPN ?

Comment: I am not sure what you trying to do? Are you asking if there a system wide capability to check if a VPN is connected? Or is the specific to one of the OpenVPN apps for Android?

Comment: I want to know that if my device is connected to VPN by installing openVPN, then from my own app how could I get to know about the status of VPN .. hope I am clear now !

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple implementation of OpenVPN for Android. One is the offical OpenVPN Connect and the other is OpenVPN for Android. The latter has no support (yet) for query/broadcasting the status of the connected VPN. Patches are welcomed. I don't know about the offical OpenVPN Connect app. I suggest contacting them if need information about their client.

Comment: Alright thanks for the reply, is there a system wide capability to check if a VPN is connected ?

Comment: I have no idea But you should search for questions regarding that issue on stackoverflow or ask your own new question

Comment: does OpenVPN for Android have any custom broadcast senders/AIDL ?